# Windows command "where arg" in xp?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-xp, command-prompt

The command "where" works for windows 2003 server and later version.
How can I do the same functionality it provides in windows XP.

Is there a similar command ?

Comment: This is not a programming question. it would be better suited to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result on XP using

```
dir /b /s C:\yourfile.txt
```

Obviously changing `C:\` to the drive you want to search.

If you want to search more than 1 drive then you can loop over them

```
for %%a in (C: D: E:) do (
dir /b /s %%a\yourfile.txt
)
```

This may not work for network drives, but this slight modification should

```
for %%a in (X: Y: Z:) do (
pushd %%a
dir /b /s yourfile.txt
popd
)
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but what if I don't know the drives letters ? 
I think your answer should work if I do know the drives letters.
am I right ?

Comment: Yeah, it will work if you know them, if you don't, then just loop over A: to Z: with the network option, then you can't go wrong.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. It will search files in all subdirectories of a specified drive instead of searching in the `PATH`.